# Use ctrl-v to paste images into an input files

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem using an input and a function to paste images.

When I copy the address of the image and paste it into the input using ctrl-v ... the url appears successfully.

My problem is that if I copy the image instead of her address, ctrl-v no longer works, that is, my pastedata is empty :(

Does anyone know how I can get this to work in both ways, that is, I can copy the image or the address that works both ways.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qkwbxf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**CODE**

```
@HostListener('paste', ['$event'])
  onPaste(e: ClipboardEvent) {
    let clipboardData = e.clipboardData || (window as any).clipboardData;
    let pastedData = clipboardData.getData('text');
    alert(pastedData)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that types of data being pasted is different.  The link is coming in as text while the other is coming in as a file.  You have to handle the different scenarios.  You can detect the different kind of data and branch out from there.

Likely you're going to convert these items to a blob.  Fortunately, in the case of images, the browser does the work for you.  There is plenty of example code converting a base64 encoded image into a blob so you should be okay there too.  Obviously you'll have to have cases for non base64 encoded image urls and just crummy irrelevant text that gets pasted by the user accidentally.

```
onPaste(e: ClipboardEvent) {
  const clipboardData = e.clipboardData || (window as any).clipboardData;
  const items: DataTransferItem[] = Array.from(clipboardData.items);
  const textData = items.find(x => x.type === 'text/plain');
  const imageData = items.find(x => /image/i.test(x.type) );
 let blob$: Observable<Blob>;
  if (imageData) {
    blob$ = of(imageData.getAsFile());
  }
  else if (textData) {
    // bindCallback throws error when passing textData.getAsString directly
    const callbackFunc = x => textData.getAsString(x);
    blob$ = bindCallback(callbackFunc)().pipe(
      tap(x => console.log(x)),
      map(/** convert to blob **/)
    );
  }
  else {
    blob$ = of(undefined);
  }
  blob$.pipe(/* do stuff with your blob. */).subscribe();
}
```